# Issues programmatically creating and using a WebBrowser C#

Tags: c#

Right now im attempting to use a `WebBrowser` to click an element. With the following code I launch a thread.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(Setting3);
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
```

Inside that thread I am running the following code to create and use that webBrowser.

```
WebBrowser b = new WebBrowser();
b.Navigate("https://example.com/find?id=" + id);
await WaitForPage(10, b); // waits for page to be loaded
b.Document.GetElementById("MyElement").InvokeMember("Click");                    
b.Dispose();
```

WaitForPage()

```
        private async Task WaitForPage(int TimeOut, WebBrowser Browser)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<bool> PageLoaded = null;
        PageLoaded = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        int TimeElapsed = 0;
        Browser.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (Browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) return;
            if (PageLoaded.Task.IsCompleted) return; PageLoaded.SetResult(true);
        };
        while (PageLoaded.Task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        {
            await Task.Delay(10);
            TimeElapsed++;
            if (TimeElapsed >= TimeOut * 100) PageLoaded.TrySetResult(true);
        }
    }
```

The issue i'm experiencing is that the element does not get clicked, it does if its on the main thread if I do it with a `webBrowser` control that's not programmatically created, it then works without an issue. I am also attempting to use the least memory possible when clicking the element. I have no idea why, does not spit out any errors, just the thread exits.

Comment: Can you post the WaitForPage function also?

Comment: @JordyvanEijk Added

Comment: Is it also possible to send the HTML that is comming from your request? i think you're not calling example.com :) Probably you have the wrong Id, do you get any exceltions?

Comment: @JordyvanEijk No exceptions, I also have a just set ID for it. After creating it the thread exits.

Comment: Bumping -- don't know if this works or is against rules.